# Install chrome extension using registry

Tags: google-chrome-extension, registry

I have an extension that is hosted in Chrome wwebstore, I want to make an installer that installs it automatically through registry, however, I seems that this method does not work anymore, and if it works it wont be activated. Is there any other possible solution after the last chrome updates.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which method you use for an installer, the extension will be initially disabled and user will be presented with a question whether he wants to enable your extension.

That said, [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry) is still the correct method. Add a key to the registry, on next launch Chrome will download the extension and present a dialog to the user.

The only way to install an extension "no questions asked" (on Windows) is through domain policies.

Comment: what is meant by domain policy ?

Comment: Enterprise installs. If the computer is part of a domain and you have domain administration rights, there's a policy: http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist